# Localize application on button click

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, resources, localization

I have in my project mainMaster page were locates imageButtons:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="RU" ImageUrl="/Images/RU.png" runat="server" onclick="RU_Click">                
<asp:ImageButton ID="USA" ImageUrl="/Images/USA.png" runat="server" onclick="USA_Click" />
```

here's OnClick functions:

```
protected void RU_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["MyCulture"] = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");
    Server.Transfer(Request.Url.LocalPath);     
}

protected void USA_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["MyCulture"] = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU");
    Server.Transfer(Request.Url.LocalPath);  
}
```

also I have two .resx files but how cane I link press buttons with

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Main, Name%>" />
```

Comment: I don't understand how link CultureInfo with onklick buttun functions, and switch text of literral on pages like this: Text="<%$ Resources:Main, Name%>"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the actual issue you are having to it, instead of in a comment.

Comment: we don't understand your question; please provide more details what you need ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but let me clear one thing up for you that might be your problem.

You can set Culture only in the `InitializeCulture` event:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-AU");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-AU");
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
protected void RU_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCulture("ru-RU");
}

protected void USA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCulture("en-UA");
}

public static void SetCulture(string culture)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
}
```

to set current culture, so localization could take effect.

Comment: Ok. like this I cane switch Culture. So I Need to switch text on the literals on pages: <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Main, ProductType%>"/>. If I have files Main.rus.resx and Main.usa.resx with Name:ProductType and Value:"String Name _1" how manage this?

Comment: @Darien: You need to name resource files in the correspondence with culture name, e.g. `Main.aspx.ru-RU.resx` and put it into `~/App_LocalResources` IIRC

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246.aspx) and [other resources](http://www.google.com/search?q=app_localresources)