# How to set localization for treeview control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, localization, dotnetnuke

i want to set the localizaiton in the asp.net control Tree view, could any body guide me how to achieve this?

```
<asp:TreeView  meta:resourcekey="TreeViewQ" ID="Q_View" runat="server">
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode  Text="FirstNode"  Value="1" >
            <asp:TreeNode Text="child1" Value="2">
        </asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Secondnode" Value="3">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="thirdnode" Value="4"></asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

i want to set localization for text property of node in the tree view.

Some More to add:- what do you infer from this, do i need to do something like this.

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" 
    runat="server" 
    meta:resourcekey="Wizard1Resource1">
  <NavigationStyle 
    BorderWidth="<%$ resources:navBorderWidth %>"/>
  <WizardSteps>
    <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" 
      runat="server" 
      Title="Step 1" 
      meta:resourcekey="WizardStep1Resource1">
    </asp:WizardStep>
  </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
```

Comment: Looking for an answer for long but no respite...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a Local resource file and it will automatically add the resource meta:

`meta:resourcekey="TreeNodeResource2"` this will point to the TreeView Node `Text Property`

```
  <asp:TreeView meta:resourcekey="TreeViewQ" ID="Q_View" runat="server">
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="FirstNode" Value="1" meta:resourcekey="TreeNodeResource2">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="child1" Value="2" meta:resourcekey="TreeNodeResource1"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Secondnode" Value="3" meta:resourcekey="TreeNodeResource4">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="thirdnode" Value="4" meta:resourcekey="TreeNodeResource3"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
```

Upon generation of the local resource, I got the following resource file...
[image]

Comment: But in resource file how should i form key-value form, and what about the defalult text which i have set to be displayed for global way, and that should change on localization from the resource file........

Comment: I have edit my answer and attach the image with key and value of resource key.

Comment: I did the same, but not working, i think i am missing how to access it in the node control to change the text property on changing to the localization.

Comment: one way you can make new page or remove all resource from the current file, Delete the Resource file and then regenerate local resource file.

Comment: no, that is not working.............i have set the values, this work for some label, text box, but not not working for the treeview, how to reset the value on......

Comment: You want to reset the value in resource files ?

Comment: i have the resource file ViewFAQ.ascx.da-DK.resx for denish there i have made changes as you explained in the KEY-VALUE form....now i want from the dop down if i select the danish it should be applicable to that tree viwe the values from the resource file....

Comment: i want to set the value from the resource file..on the danish selection.thats it

Comment: Are you sure your localization implementation work properly ? are you doing like in my answer  ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097520/localize-application-on-button-click/6098454#6098454

Comment: yes i did the same it works for the link button..but not for tree view...:(

Comment: it is DNN, has intenally all things set i just have to select appropriate language from the drop down and all resource files are already created there. i just have to set  the key value pair, it all works fine for the label, textbox but not for treeview to set resource key like that

Comment: if we make text above in your code empty like "" then how to set it from the resource file..because i make it empty then treeview nodes becomes empty...

Comment: I can't see any issue, there must be the other problem. Can you make new page and just add the treeview which you have added in question and generate resource file and check whether its working or not ?

Comment: not working man, i am having user control where i need to do this

Comment: But I have shown that it is working to my side. I don't know the issue then.

Comment: do you think i need to use it with some sub property, or with parent child kind of relationship.....or it will work directly as you told, i am using use control, for link button it works fine..